# How to clean the #route path after the click in the menu

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-ui-router

I have a small menu that helps the user to navigate around the same page by scrolling to the option:

```html
<div class="listContainer">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="list-group" id="list-tab" routerLinkActive="active-link">
        <ul>
           <li><a routerLink="./" [fragment]="'stockunityinformation_title'">Stock Unity Information</a></li>
           <li><a routerLink="./" [fragment]="'addtionalreferences_title'">Addtional references</a></li>
           <li><a routerLink="./" [fragment]="'warehouse_information_title'">Warehouse Information</a></li>
           <li><a routerLink="./" [fragment]="'serialnumber_title'">Serial Number</a></li>
           <li><a routerLink="./" [fragment]="'TransactionHistory_title'">Transaction History</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

The problem with this is that if the user clicks at the option "TransactionHistory_title" for example, scroll up and then click at the same option again, it wont work because the route is set in the url already.

How can I 'reset' the route after the click?

localhost:4200/detailview#TransactionHistory_title

Instead of having the example above, after the click and the redirect to the element, have an URL like this:

localhost:4200/detailview

I don't have much experience with angular and html so please, if possible, make the explanation newbie friendly.

Thank you very much! =)

Answer (score 1):

I'm use for scroll ngx-scroll package

```
<button [ngx-scroll-to]="'#destination'">Go to destination</button>

 <div id="destination">
   You've reached your destination.
 </div>

  npm i @nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to
```

[ngx-schroll-to package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to)

```
...
 import { ScrollToModule } from '@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to';
 ...

@NgModule({
 imports: [
  ...
  ScrollToModule.forRoot()
  ],
  ...
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  })
 export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Hi Boris, thank you for the answer, I tested it and works very well but, the problem is that the architecture said that he does not want npm packages in the project due to maintainability problems.

Comment: if you can use .   JQUERY in you project .  

look my [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52090011/10263768)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
<a [routerLink]="['/']" [queryParams]="{}"> Applications</a>
```

or this

```
<a [routerLink]="['/']" [queryParams]="{selected: true}"> Applications</a>
```

or this

```
this._router.navigate(['/'], {queryParams: {selected: true}});
```

or this

```
this.router.navigate(['/'], { fragment: 'top' });
```